# How to add a directory to my path that includes a colon and a space?

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I installed [MIT/GNU scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) and am trying to add the directory to my `$PATH` variable so that I can run it from Terminal.

The app name `MIT:GNU Scheme.app` is a veritable "perfect storm" (for path names) as it includes a colon and a space.

I've tried adding each of the following to my `~/.bash_profile`, none have worked:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/other/paths:/Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources"
export PATH=$PATH:"/other/paths:/Applications/MIT\:GNU Scheme.app/Contents/Resources"
export PATH=${PATH}:"/other/paths:/Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources"
export PATH=${PATH}:"/other/paths:/Applications/MIT\:GNU Scheme.app/Contents/Resources"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work. You have several options:

1. Create an alias for bash to run the command.
2. Create a symbolic link to the executable from a directory in your PATH. (I like to have a directory `~/bin` at the front of my path for such things.)
3. Create a symbolic link to `/Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources` somewhere and put the link in your PATH.
4. Rename the application.

Comment: Creating an alias worked, thanks. A symbolic link to the directory didn't for some reason, something specific to the app, I suppose. Is it OK to just rename a .app and have everything work as it should?

Comment: I am not sure if just renaming the app will work. Perhaps you need to change the value of `CFBundleDisplayName` inside `Contents/Info.plist` as well.

Comment: I'll stick with the alias, was just curious whether that was allowed.